# Problem with scraping product dimension off of woocommerce online shop

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Somehow my web scraper doesn't grab the product dimensions.
Html:

```
<div class="woodmart-tab-wrapper">
    <a href="#tab-additional_information" class="woodmart-accordion-title tab-title-additional_information">Additional Information</a>
    <div class="woocommerce-Tabs-panel woocommerce-Tabs-panel--additional_information panel entry-content wc-tab" id="tab-additional_information">
    <div class="wc-tab-inner ">
    <div class="">
    <table class="shop_attributes">
    <tr>## Heading ##
    <th>Size</th>
    <td class="product_dimensions">32 x 24 x 10 cm</td>
    </tr>
```

I want to grab "32 x 24 x 10 cm". My code: I tried scraping it through css_selectors, rel xpath and abs xpath nothing seems to work.

```
dimensions = ''
    try:
        dimensions = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            '.product_dimensions').text
    except Exception as e:
        dimensions = '-'
```

And

```
 dimensions = ''
    try:
        dimensions = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//td[contains(@class,'product_dimensions')]").text
    except Exception as e:
        dimensions = '-'
```

The output when there are no dimensions for the product is:

```
dimensions: -
```

But when there are dimensions for the product the output is just:

```
dimensions:
```

Comment: The "product_dimensions" class is only used once on the whole product page, so yes it is the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to click on the `additional info` (*zusätzliche information*
) tab to gain access to that element's value.

**Using CSS selector:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://designerparadies.de/produkt/schultertasche-trunk-aus-leder/'
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get(url)
d.find_element_by_css_selector('[href*=additional_information]').click()
print(d.find_element_by_css_selector('.product_dimensions').text)
d.quit()
```

**Using xpath:**

```
d.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'additional_information_tab')]").click()
```

---

**Additional info tab:**

[image]

Comment: That is odd. Can you check if adding a wait works? Also, which line does that occur on?

Comment: Added one. Maybe I made a mistake implementing your code. This is how it looks right now. oh and it doesn't show a line in which it occurs but it never happened so it has to be in the "size" part of the code.
size = ''
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'additional_information_tab')]").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        size = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//td[contains(@class,'product_dimensions')]").text
    except Exception as e:
        size = '-'

Comment: you don't use = for the click it is an event. If you use my code exactly as is what happens?

Comment: I didn't use = for the click  event I used it in the next line to save it. I just tested your code and it returned the dimensions. Would you be so kind to show me how to implement it into my code? https://imgur.com/vUvBucD

Comment: I accepted the answer and thank you for all the help so far :) https://pastebin.com/nJAT7TWb
Search for "size"

Comment: That is a lot code. I will have a look this evening.

Comment: So, do you have an idea how to implement it into my code? :s

Comment: Haven’t forgotten you.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you are using `Selenium`. Is there any reason for not using `bs4` (Beautiful Soup) or any other web scraping module?

If you need to bypass some kind of JavaScript challenge or something, I **strongly** recommend you to:

1. Obtain the HTML source code using `Selenium`
2. Use Beautiful Soup module to extract the information you need

As far as I can say, whenever I needed to do some web scraping for any personal project, I usually found Beautiful Soup much easier to use and very well documented (in oposition with Selenium)

Here you have a sample program that may fit your requirements

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = Options()
# Use --headless in order to hide the browser window
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

# get the page and obtain it's source
driver.get("http://example.com/woocom")
source = driver.page_source

# Use BeautifulSoup to create and Object which contains
# every element in the webpage
page_object = BeautifulSoup(source , features="html.parser")

# If there is more one td with the "product_dimensions" class, we want to
# get everyone and then loop over them to get their text
dimensions = []
product_dimensions = page_object.findall("td", class_= "product_dimensions")
for element in product_dimensions:
    dimensions.append(element.get_text())

# If there is only one td with the "product_dimensions" class, then use "find" instead
# of "findall"
product_dimensions = page_object.find("td", class_= "product_dimensions").get_text()
```

If you don't need to bypass any JavaScript or similar, just replace the `driver.get("http://example.com/woocom")` with `requests.get("http://example.com/woocom")` (remember to import the `requests` library and delete `source = driver.page_source` because you won't need it as `requests.get()` returns the page source by itself)

I hope this helps, however, when asking something, please, try to give as much information as possible in order to help other people to answer you